# When I POST from Nodejs to an API run on Django rest framework. It returns 200 ok but in database nothing saved

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, postgresql, django-rest-framework

1. When I POST from Nodejs to an API run on Django rest framework. It returns 200 ok but in database nothing saved.
   2.The Api Calls here is run on Django restframework.
2. The Database used--> Postgres
3. snippet: js Then html

   ```js
    function handleSubmit(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var x = document.getElementById('Date');
      var y = x.value;
      document.getElementById('Date').value = y;
      if (x != y) {
      x = document.getElementById('Date');
      y = x.value;
      console.log(y);
      const data = document.getElementById('form');        
      fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/sender', {
      method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
      headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      }).then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
      console.log('Success:', data);
      }).catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
      });
      } else {
      x = document.getElementById('Date');
      y = x.value;
      console.log(y);
      }
      }

      const form = document.querySelector('form');
      form.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit);
   ```

   ```html
     <form id="form">
            <label for="SenderId">Your Id:</label>
            <input type="text" name="SenderId" id="id"> <br>
            <label for="SenderName">Your Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="SenderName" id="SenderName"> <br>
            <label for="SenderAddress">Your Address:</label>
            <input type="text" name="SenderAddress" id="SenderAddress"> <br>
            <label for="SenderPO">Your PO:</label>
            <input type="text" name="SenderPostOffice" id="SenderPostOffice"> <br>
            <label for="Date">Date:</label>
            <input type="date" name="Date" id="Date">
            <label for="PackageCount">Package Count:</label>
            <input type="text" name="PackageCount" id="PackageCount"> <br>
            <button type="submit">Send</button>
        </form>
      <!-- end snippet -->
   ```

Comment: is this issue happening when to test in postman?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow - please review the [guidelines on how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - this will help you to get useful answers to your question.

Comment: No, from postman the api accepts all kind of request.
Body-->raw-->json in this way....